# Cannot cast from void to String in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to save the error printed on the command line by (`e.printStackTrace()`) in a StringBuilder Variable which i then export to a txt file However i am getting an error cannot cast from void to String ? Can someone please explain to me why i cannot cast it to String and if there is a alternate strategy to saving it ?

```
StringBuilder error_logs = new StringBuilder();

catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

                    error_logs.append(e.printStackTrace());
        }
```

Comment: What does `e.printStackTrace()` do?

Comment: `printStackTrace` doesn't return anything -- that's what `void` for a return type means.

Comment: If you want a stack trace in a variable you need to use `getStackTrace` and hen format it yourself.  Or do `printStackTrace` to a `PrintWriter` on a `String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.printStackTrace` only prints the stack trace, but does not return it. You can use `e.getStackTrace()` and then write it to the log the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringWriter wtr = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pwtr = new PrintWriter(wtr);
e.printStackTrace(pwtr);
String stackTrace = wtr.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`printStackTrace()` is a function of the Exception class that writes the stack trace to the outstream. It does not return a string representation of the Error. You can use `getStackTrace()` as someone has already mentioned, but it does not return a string representation of the stack trace, but rather an array of StackTraceElements. If you're trying to write the Stack trace to a file, you can use the PrintStream version of the function `printStackTrace( PrintStream s )` to pass in a PrintStream to the function that will store the string.